# What Happens to the Controller When the Window is Closed?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, window

If I have a 2 `Window`s open and both have controllers, what happens to the controller of the closed `Window` if I close the window (not the root node) from the mentioned controller? Is the controller garbage collected, does any remaining code run?

Comment: Can you give a code example how you set up your windows and controllers?  The answer is "it depends" so we have to see how your code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no other custom code is holding a reference to the scenegraph produced by the FXML. You could also fire up a memory analyzer like Eclipse MAT to inspect your heap.